# How to execute 2 or more Hardcoded Insert Statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anybody have an idea how to execute the following code in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO DLAccountingSystem.tblUserType
(UserTypeName, PermissionXML, LastEditUser, LastEditDate)
VALUES
('Admin', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE());

INSERT INTO DLAccountingSystem.tblUserType
(UserTypeName, PermissionXML, LastEditUser, LastEditDate)
VALUES
('Accountant', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE());

INSERT INTO DLAccountingSystem.tblUserType
(UserTypeName, PermissionXML, LastEditUser, LastEditDate)
VALUES
('Encoder', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE());
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you've got? You want to insert them all at once in a single round-trip, or all with the same date, or something else? Doesn't it just work? And why hard-code them? Why not use a parametrised query three times?

Comment: yes somehow MySQL Query browser is just inserting the first:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref:[INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

The values list for each row must be enclosed within parentheses. The following statement is illegal because the number of values in the list does not match the number of column names:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Edit: Simple example of [Insert multiple records into MySQL with a single query](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)

```
INSERT INTO DLAccountingSystem.tblUserType
(UserTypeName, PermissionXML, LastEditUser, LastEditDate)
VALUES
('Admin', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE()),
('Accountant', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE()),
('Encoder', '', 'Admin User', CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

Following statement will insert three records. Follow the same approach.

```
INSERTINTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);
```

Comment: This worked! Great Thanks.. :) just curious, Is this gonna work also with MS SQL server?

Comment: Yes, it will also work with sql server but it will work sql server 2008 onwards. refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html to speed up multiple insert statements in mysql.